# Why does string.contains ("text") not work with strings in swift 5?

Tags: swift, string, contains

```
let string = "hello Swift"
if string.contains("Swift") {
    print("exists")
}
```

Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character')

Why is version 5 such an error and what should I do?

Comment: You'll need to `import Foundation`

Comment: I just tried your code on **swift-5.0.2** and everything works perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `contains()` and pass it a `String`, Swift tries to use an overload of the function that takes some kind of string like **contains(_ other: StringProtocol)** function that is not part of the pure Swift `String`. Instead it finds **contains(_ element: Character)** and it can't accept String as an argument and only accepts **'String.Element' (aka 'Character')**. Referring to [contains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2893238-contains)

The function you are looking for is defined in a protocol that String conforms to it, called `StringProtocol` that lives inside the `Foundation`.

So if you need it, make sure you `import Foundation` or a higher level framework like `UIKit`.

Comment: To add more detail, It's from `StringProtocol` and you can see in the documentation for [`contains`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/3126753-contains) that it is from Foundation.